# ListView with Numberpicker

Tags: android, listview, numberpicker

I have a problem with displaying Numberpicker in a listview :

the Numberpicker exist in the layout list_item

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    records=new ArrayList<Product>();
    listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
    listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    String[] nums = new String[20];
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
        nums[i] = Integer.toString(i);
    np.setMinValue(1);
    np.setMaxValue(20);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np.setValue(1);
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: It doesn't show  correctly i can't increment or decrement

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You're creating a string array and populating it with numbers as strings but you're not using it anywhere. What do you mean by " i can't increment or decrement "? Can you post your layout please?

Comment: Thanks , the numberpicker wasn't in the right layout .